# Como abrir arquivo .csv contendo "ç" no rótulo das colunas com o Python

Tags: python, csv

Estou iniciando no *Python* e estou com um problema: preciso abrir um arquivo `.csv` no *Python*, porém no cabeçalho das colunas contém um `ç`.

Quando tento abrir ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 17: invalid continuation byte

Abaixo um trecho do meu código:

```
import pandas as pd

caminhoarquivo = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\teste.csv'

basedados = pd.read_csv(caminhoarquivo,sep=';',decimal=',')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Vejamos...**

Seu arquivo `CSV` está, muito provavelmente, em uma *codificação diferente* de `UTF-8`. Geralmente essa codificação pode ser `Latin-1`. Se o arquivo foi criado por você, fica fácil determinar ao verificar o programa que o criou.

**Solução**

Modifique a codificação de conversão de `read_csv`. Como exemplo, considerando que seja `Latin-1`, troque

```
basedados = pd.read_csv(caminhoarquivo, sep=';', decimal=',')
```

Por

```
basedados = pd.read_csv(caminhoarquivo, sep=';', decimal=',', encoding='latin-1')
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu acredito que você tenha que usar encoding='utf-8'
ficando assim:
basedados = pd.read_csv(caminhoarquivo, sep=';', decimal=',', encoding='utf-8' )